# Python chat application

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, sockets

I am trying to write a simple chat server, that takes message from 1 user and sends to all other users. The other users can simultaneously send messages and receive them.

On client side one thread continuously waits for messages and other thread sends messages.

```
import socket
import threading

def getMessage(s):
    while True:
        s.send(raw_input("Message: "))

#Main
port = 1041
host = 'localhost'
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))

background_thread = threading.Thread(target=getMessage, args=(s,))
background_thread.daemon = True
background_thread.start()

while True:
    print s.recv(1024)
```

On server side the server, takes the incoming connection request, opens a new thread for each new request and waits for their messages, when a connection sends a message, the server broadcasts it to all other connections that are open.

```
import socket
from thread import *

def ClientThread(connection, clients):
    while True:
        message = connection.recv(1024)
        connection.send("Ack\n")
        broadcast(connection, clients, message)


def broadcast(connection, clients, message):
    for conn in clients:
        if(conn != connection):
            conn.send(message)

def AcceptConnections(clients):
    while True:
        connection, address = s.accept()
        print "Got connection from ",connection
        clients.append(connection)
        start_new_thread(ClientThread, (connection, clients))


#Main
print "Started server"
port = 1041
host = 'localhost'
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

clients = []
AcceptConnections(clients)
```

Expected: When one client sends a message, all other connected clients receive that message, irrespective of them typing and sending a message.

Reality: Other clients receive the message only after they send 1 or 2 messages.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly for me.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Did you try with 2 clients ? When one of my client is sending the messages, the other client doesn't receive it until it sends a message.

Comment: I tried with 3 clients, every client could send messages, every client received every message from every other client.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Ok so I think this just happens when I open idle window, it works fine in cmd window